# "Save As" Button On PDF, in android

Tags: android, acrobat

I have created a small app that opens a PDF in Android.  The PDf has a "Save As" button that I created using the wizard in acrobat.  The button works on the PC but is not active when I open the PDF in Android.  The Mailto button works just fine.  My question is is there a place or a way to script an android command to Saveas in the PDF itself.  Could the "Submit" button be changed to sendto a file in the external storage?

Thanks,
MAxxDAddy

Comment: What app are you using to display the PDF?

Comment: I am using adobe reader for android.  thanks!!

Comment: Adobe Reader for Android is quite limited; afaik, it does not support much beyond display of PDFs.

Comment: so you are saying the problem is the reader.  I will try some PDF applications tonight to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Good luck. I've looked through pretty much all of them, and none support scripting.

Comment: well that's a bummer, funny that the submit button works just fine but the save as does not.  it even opens the prompt for gmail, but you are correct, tried a couple more and no dice.  :/